# What does the dd command do?

Tags: root, command-line

Someone rooted my box and executed a command, help!

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=.huehuehue
```

what does this command do?

Comment: How do you know someone rooted your system? How did you find out this command was run?

Answer (score 2):

`dd` is the command for copying and checking from an `i`nput `f`ile `if` to an`o`utput `f`ile `of`.

Taken together, the command means to copy content from the input file, in this instance `/dev/random`, a pseudo-random number generator, into a file called `.huehuehue`.

I don't think this is a question particularly related to Ubuntu, personally, but it was asked here. Maybe this should be shifted to *[unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)* ?

You might also want to try running `ps aux | grep dd` to see if the process is still running. Get the process number and `kill` it.

I hope there was no other damage if this was a genuine case.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said it fills up a file with random data.

You might ask, well, why would an attacker want to do that?

The likely reason is that, by using up all the space on the disk, it will overwrite any blocks containing data from deleted files, which may cover their tracks.

Answer (score 1):

That fills up your file system by reading from a pseudo-random number generator and outputting it to a file named ".huehuehue". It's hilarious.

It's probably done running by now. Just delete the file.

```
sudo find / -name .huehuehue -print -delete
```

If your box got rooted, you're going to want to wipe the drives and re-install. It takes longer to do the forensic work to prove they haven't added in some rootkit or timebomb that it does to just re-install.

Comment: how can i kill this process pidof dd is null

Comment: What do you mean it's null?